# Homebrew does not think XCode is installed with old XCode and current Homebrew

Tags: node.js, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew, xcode3.2

I am trying to install node.js but am still running OSX 10.6.8, and thus am stuck with XCode 3 (using 3.2).

My first issue, is that I cannot get homebrew to recognize XCode 3.2.  When I run `brew -v doctor` I get the following output (after fixing a few other issues):

```
Homebrew 0.9.4
Warning: Setting DYLD_* vars can break dynamic linking. 
Set variables:
    DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Warning: Xcode not installed
Most stuff needs Xcode to build: http://developer.apple.com/xcode/
```

I have only been able to find fixes for XCode 4.xx and they have not worked for me.  How do I point homebrew at my XCode? (I also don't really understand how I should set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`...)

When I run `brew install node` I am told that xcode is not installed (it definitely is), and also this error: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'out/Release/node'`

The fixes I have seen for this relate to XCode (various `xcode-select -switch` fixes), but they have not worked for me, as these fixes have been for XCode 4.xx.

When I run the verbose version, this error additionally shows up:

```
creating  ./config.gypi
creating  ./config.mk
sh: /usr/bin/usr/bin/xcodebuild: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/usr/bin/xcodebuild fails with 32512 - Unknown error: 32512

gyp: Error 69 running xcodebuild
```

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

While homebrew is great for a lot of packages I have never had good luck using it for node.js. Can you install using the standard [OSX binary](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.3/node-v0.10.3.pkg)?

Also [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is really good if you need to work with multiple versions of node.js

Comment: Thanks, that worked, for node.js! But I'm hesitant to mark it as the answer, as I would still like to be able to point homebrew to XCode if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might now have the Xcode CLI tools installed. You can install them from the Xcode preferences.